# How does jqGrid's serializeCellData work?

Tags: jqgrid

I think that serializeCellData would be useful to me, but I'm not sure how it works and where it is called in the order of events. Does serializeCellData(postdata) define the other event parameters rowid, cellname, value, iRow, and iCol? Can it be used to add postdata information to, for instance, afterSaveCell so that it now takes more than 5 arguments?

In my code, I'm making local modifications to data using cell editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) event can be used to customize the data which will be send to the server in case of cell submitting. It will be used only if [cellsubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#properties) option are set to 'remote' of course. For example, if we save the cell named `'mycell'` (the cell from the column 'mycell') the object `{id: theRowId, mycell: cellValue}` will be used as the `postdata` parameter of [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) event. If you want you can analyse the input and return from [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) the object like `{rowid: theRowId, cellname:mycell, value: cellvalue}`. If you need to have access to additional information like `iRow` and `iCol` you can implement additionally [beforeSubmitCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events), save the values of parameters which you need in a variable in the external scope which is visible in both [beforeSubmitCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) and [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events). Then you can see the values saved by [beforeSubmitCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) inside of [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) and append the object returned by [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events).

What I described above is only some remrks how the [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) event can be used. If you return the string from your [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) event handler instead on an obect then the string will be send by `jQuery.ajax` exactly like it be. So if you need to send JSON data to the server you can do the following

```
serializeCellData: function(postdata) {
    return JSON.stringify(postdata);
}
```

So the [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) event can be used in different cases and gives you really **full control** which data exactly will be send to the server.

Comment: So if I use the customized serializeCellData object you described above, the cellurl will be appended (assuming GET) with &id=4&cellname=mycell&value=cellValue?

Comment: @Andrea: Exactly! But for editing will be typically use HTTP POST or HTTP PUT and not GET because GET requests can be cached which is bad in case of editing.